# ISP Blocking SNI Extension (Server Name Identifier) In Windows 10 But Not Server 2016

Tags: certificate, isp, sniffing, traffic-filtering

Out of curiosity I noticed my ISP (talktalk - UK) was able to block certain websites by the SNI Extention, however only from Windows 10. When attempting to access the same website from Server 2016, it succedes.

I captured the traffic using wireshark from both a windows 10 VM and a Server 2016 VM and noticed the folowing differences in the TLS client hello packet. Logged using FireFox, although any browser has the same result.

Can anyone advise? Looks like there is a difference in the initial TLS version. Immediately folowing the Windows 10 client hello I get a TCP RST flag (Reset) back from the server's IP (and get's blocked). This does not happen in server 2016.

[Blocked Screenshot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uiMm.png)

**Windows 10 (Blocked by ISP):**

```
Transport Layer Security
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 512
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 508
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random: 182ee4b40150007b6ee7d849f95f5bac687ec50b700f64e5…
            GMT Unix Time: Nov  9, 1982 21:46:28.000000000 GMT Standard Time
            Random Bytes: 0150007b6ee7d849f95f5bac687ec50b700f64e50dd805cc…
        Session ID Length: 32
        Session ID: 72a08438398989047259317a73d22dd941bf848fff0e7257…
        Cipher Suites Length: 36
        Cipher Suites (18 suites)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
            Compression Method: null (0)
        Extensions Length: 399
        Extension: server_name (len=13)
            Type: server_name (0)
            Length: 13
            Server Name Indication extension
                Server Name list length: 11
                Server Name Type: host_name (0)
                Server Name length: 8
                Server Name: rarbg.to
        Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
            Type: extended_master_secret (23)
            Length: 0
        Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
            Type: renegotiation_info (65281)
            Length: 1
            Renegotiation Info extension
                Renegotiation info extension length: 0
        Extension: supported_groups (len=14)
            Type: supported_groups (10)
            Length: 14
            Supported Groups List Length: 12
            Supported Groups (6 groups)
                Supported Group: x25519 (0x001d)
                Supported Group: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                Supported Group: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                Supported Group: secp521r1 (0x0019)
                Supported Group: ffdhe2048 (0x0100)
                Supported Group: ffdhe3072 (0x0101)
        Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
            Type: ec_point_formats (11)
            Length: 2
            EC point formats Length: 1
            Elliptic curves point formats (1)
                EC point format: uncompressed (0)
        Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
            Type: session_ticket (35)
            Length: 0
            Data (0 bytes)
        Extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation (len=14)
            Type: application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)
            Length: 14
            ALPN Extension Length: 12
            ALPN Protocol
                ALPN string length: 2
                ALPN Next Protocol: h2
                ALPN string length: 8
                ALPN Next Protocol: http/1.1
        Extension: status_request (len=5)
            Type: status_request (5)
            Length: 5
            Certificate Status Type: OCSP (1)
            Responder ID list Length: 0
            Request Extensions Length: 0
        Extension: key_share (len=107)
            Type: key_share (51)
            Length: 107
            Key Share extension
                Client Key Share Length: 105
                Key Share Entry: Group: x25519, Key Exchange length: 32
                    Group: x25519 (29)
                    Key Exchange Length: 32
                    Key Exchange: 078fdff07806eb707ef0cf0826908e7b85da6dd2041f855d…
                Key Share Entry: Group: secp256r1, Key Exchange length: 65
                    Group: secp256r1 (23)
                    Key Exchange Length: 65
                    Key Exchange: 0415220711d4bb416d47074ca2de7ec7ba4bd610bec96747…
        Extension: supported_versions (len=9)
            Type: supported_versions (43)
            Length: 9
            Supported Versions length: 8
            Supported Version: TLS 1.3 (0x0304)
            Supported Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Supported Version: TLS 1.1 (0x0302)
            Supported Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Extension: signature_algorithms (len=24)
            Type: signature_algorithms (13)
            Length: 24
            Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 22
            Signature Hash Algorithms (11 algorithms)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256 (0x0403)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384 (0x0503)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512 (0x0603)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256 (0x0804)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (4)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384 (0x0805)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (5)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512 (0x0806)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (6)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha384 (0x0501)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha512 (0x0601)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_sha1 (0x0203)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha1 (0x0201)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
        Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
            Type: psk_key_exchange_modes (45)
            Length: 2
            PSK Key Exchange Modes Length: 1
            PSK Key Exchange Mode: PSK with (EC)DHE key establishment (psk_dhe_ke) (1)
        Extension: record_size_limit (len=2)
            Type: record_size_limit (28)
            Length: 2
            Record Size Limit: 16385
        Extension: padding (len=150)
            Type: padding (21)
            Length: 150
            Padding Data: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000…
```

**Server 2016 (Allowed)**

```
Transport Layer Security
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 512
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 508
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random: 1867472afaf40a1111cf68f2fd10f5f808e0b411dcf0f5b4…
            GMT Unix Time: Dec 22, 1982 16:13:30.000000000 GMT Standard Time
            Random Bytes: faf40a1111cf68f2fd10f5f808e0b411dcf0f5b45e5f0357…
        Session ID Length: 32
        Session ID: 72d9204a4438425364339b8d8a9a8f878f6f23341000f5a9…
        Cipher Suites Length: 36
        Cipher Suites (18 suites)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
            Compression Method: null (0)
        Extensions Length: 399
        Extension: server_name (len=13)
            Type: server_name (0)
            Length: 13
            Server Name Indication extension
                Server Name list length: 11
                Server Name Type: host_name (0)
                Server Name length: 8
                Server Name: rarbg.to
        Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
            Type: extended_master_secret (23)
            Length: 0
        Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
            Type: renegotiation_info (65281)
            Length: 1
            Renegotiation Info extension
                Renegotiation info extension length: 0
        Extension: supported_groups (len=14)
            Type: supported_groups (10)
            Length: 14
            Supported Groups List Length: 12
            Supported Groups (6 groups)
                Supported Group: x25519 (0x001d)
                Supported Group: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                Supported Group: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                Supported Group: secp521r1 (0x0019)
                Supported Group: ffdhe2048 (0x0100)
                Supported Group: ffdhe3072 (0x0101)
        Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
            Type: ec_point_formats (11)
            Length: 2
            EC point formats Length: 1
            Elliptic curves point formats (1)
                EC point format: uncompressed (0)
        Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
            Type: session_ticket (35)
            Length: 0
            Data (0 bytes)
        Extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation (len=14)
            Type: application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)
            Length: 14
            ALPN Extension Length: 12
            ALPN Protocol
                ALPN string length: 2
                ALPN Next Protocol: h2
                ALPN string length: 8
                ALPN Next Protocol: http/1.1
        Extension: status_request (len=5)
            Type: status_request (5)
            Length: 5
            Certificate Status Type: OCSP (1)
            Responder ID list Length: 0
            Request Extensions Length: 0
        Extension: key_share (len=107)
            Type: key_share (51)
            Length: 107
            Key Share extension
                Client Key Share Length: 105
                Key Share Entry: Group: x25519, Key Exchange length: 32
                    Group: x25519 (29)
                    Key Exchange Length: 32
                    Key Exchange: d7fa97d7b3f594dcafea8cd2df0d260b3b13aa95175aec6d…
                Key Share Entry: Group: secp256r1, Key Exchange length: 65
                    Group: secp256r1 (23)
                    Key Exchange Length: 65
                    Key Exchange: 048a12885f2de13477cc7dcdb43f450576cdb92551f48144…
        Extension: supported_versions (len=9)
            Type: supported_versions (43)
            Length: 9
            Supported Versions length: 8
            Supported Version: TLS 1.3 (0x0304)
            Supported Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Supported Version: TLS 1.1 (0x0302)
            Supported Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Extension: signature_algorithms (len=24)
            Type: signature_algorithms (13)
            Length: 24
            Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 22
            Signature Hash Algorithms (11 algorithms)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256 (0x0403)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384 (0x0503)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512 (0x0603)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256 (0x0804)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (4)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384 (0x0805)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (5)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512 (0x0806)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (6)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha384 (0x0501)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha512 (0x0601)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_sha1 (0x0203)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha1 (0x0201)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
        Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
            Type: psk_key_exchange_modes (45)
            Length: 2
            PSK Key Exchange Modes Length: 1
            PSK Key Exchange Mode: PSK with (EC)DHE key establishment (psk_dhe_ke) (1)
        Extension: record_size_limit (len=2)
            Type: record_size_limit (28)
            Length: 2
            Record Size Limit: 16385
        Extension: padding (len=150)
            Type: padding (21)
            Length: 150
            Padding Data: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000…
```

Comment: "Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)" - Disable TLSv1.0 on whatever browser you are using.  This will force the use of TLSv1.2.  If that still does not work, then verify, you are not using your ISPs DNS.

Comment: @Ramhound: record-level version in ClientHello doesn't matter, especially in TLS>1.3< which this is; see RFC8446 4.1.2 and 5.1. OP: DNS is a good point. Since you have capture(s?), look if both attempts were going to the _correct_ IPaddr.

Comment: IP address on both OS's was unchanged and matched the correct server. RST packet clearly spoofed but same IP. DNS servers set 8.8.8.8, no mofification / Man-In-Middle occured, again IP of server correct. Wondering if it's just their firewall filter logic (IF protocol = tlsv1 THEN..."). Any idea how to emulate the record protocol version to test?